# Where can I find good data on volume of air traffic?

Tags: commercial-aviation, accidents

I want to have a look at air traffic fatalities data, and have found good information on number of accidents, like [this on AviationSafety](http://aviation-safety.net/statistics/period/stats.php?cat=A1).

For comparison I want some (world-wide) data on passenger air traffic volume, like number of flights (journeys) per year, or passenger-km per year. So far I couldn't find it. Some good reference?

Answer (score 4):

For $799 you can buy IATA's [World Air Transport Statistics (WATS)](https://www.iata.org/publications/Pages/wats.aspx)

IATA publish a few summary data values in various reports

- [Scheduled Passenger - Kilometres Flown](https://www.iata.org/publications/Pages/wats-passenger-km.aspx)
- [Scheduled Passengers Carried](https://www.iata.org/publications/pages/wats-passenger-carried.aspx)
- [IATA Annual Review 2013](http://www.iata.org/about/documents/iata-annual-review-2013-en.pdf)
- [IATA Annual Review 2014](http://www.iata.org/publications/documents/iata-annual-review-2014-en.pdf)
- [IATA Statistics](https://www.iata.org/pressroom/facts_figures/fact_sheets/Documents/industry-facts.pdf)

Note that I think this is data is only collected from IATA members and much of the data is for western-built jets (figures for other manufacturers are much worse, according to comments in IATA reports)

```
Passenger Km
Total (International + Domestic)

Rank  Airline                   Millions
1     United Airlines           286,802
2     Delta Air Lines           277,560
3     Emirates                  209,377
4     American Airlines         206,551
5     China Southern Airlines   147,841
6     Southwest Airlines        145,124
7     Lufthansa                 144,236
8     Air France                136,405
9     British Airways           130,129
10    Qantas Airways            110,203
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: The 2.97 billion passengers travelled in the last slide – is that a total over several years? Or is that the number for 2012?

Answer (score 2):

I think extensive world-wide statistics will be very difficult to compile since it would be spread across so many sources. There are  Narrowing it down to Europe and America I think would make it a lot easier...

I did a search with reference to ICAO, the International Civil Aviation Organisation (a branch of the UN), but the data appeared to be behind a paywall. The World Bank however does have [data](http://data.worldbank.org/indicator/IS.AIR.PSGR) for most countries, again based on ICAO data.

Some nice and detailed data for America appears can be found at the [Bureau of Transportation Statics](http://www.rita.dot.gov/bts/sites/rita.dot.gov.bts/files/subject_areas/airline_information/index.html), part of the Department of Transportation.